# JPA Hibernate does not bind numeric variable like it does for string variable

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, binding

I'm having an issue where I can't seem to bind the numeric variables to a JPA hibernate query, like I do for any string type variables.

`Predicate predicate = cb.equal(root.get("age"), age); //int variable
 predicate = cb.equal(root.get("name"), name); //string variable`

The query hibernate creates:

`select * from ( select emp0_.emp_id as emp_id1_10_0_, 
                 empdeta1_.emp_name as emp_name1_25_1_, 
                 empdeta1.emp_age as emp_age1_10_0 
                 where empdeta1.emp_name=? 
                 and empdeta1.emp_age=25 ) 
 where rownum <= ?`

So, as we can see, emp_name is having a proper bind variable while age does not. It gets hard coded as a literal.

Has anyone, else also faced this issue?

Comment: what is the issue? that 25 shows as literal instead of `?`

Comment: Yes. It is causing a DB performance issue. It will fill up the shared pool with every query with checks for different age value.

Comment: but isn't 25 the value of your `age` variable ?

Comment: Yes. The name too has a value. But the query is correctly binding the name value but not age.
I want the query to be like:

`select * from ( select emp0_.emp_id as emp_id1_10_0_, 
                 empdeta1_.emp_name as emp_name1_25_1_, 
                 empdeta1.emp_age as emp_age1_10_0 
                 where empdeta1.emp_name=? 
                 and empdeta1.emp_age=? ) 
 where rownum <= ?`

Comment: The name value being a String has to be escaped, not the age value, that might be why you see it like that ?

Comment: Either way I don't understand why it's an issue for your use case ?

Comment: We use statement caching in Oracle. So if the numeric argument has a hard coed value every time, we will never be able to cache that statement. Every select statement with a different age will be treated as a new statement by Oracle. Ultimately, it will just fill up the shared cache pool and performance will deteriorate!